# Fading to white color

Tags: android, android-animation

I want my ImageView to turn black smoothly

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.1"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>
```

These anims turn the imageView to white, How can I turn the ImageView to black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpha represents how transparent the view is. A alpha value of 0 is invisible, and an alpha of 1 is completely opaque. So in your code you are animating your ImageView from being opaque to nearly invisible (0.1).

I think it is turning white because the content behind the ImageView is white. You could try putting the ImageView inside a View of the same size that has a black background.